# Select Tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, marquee-tool

For some reason, when I try to drag my cursor to create a rectangle with the Select Tool on Photoshop, all I end up creating is a very small bubble of selected background. No matter what I do, I always produce this small, same-sized, rounded square of selected background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the Select Tool? Rectangular Marquee Tool?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dont have it set to fixed size:

[image]

Try changing it to "normal".